# Jasmine. Module is undefined even when angular-mocks used

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I use Grunt and grunt-contrib-jasmine to start jasmine tests.

My config in Gruntfile:

```
jasmine : {
            src : ['src/main/webapp/app/js/controllers/*.js'],
            options: {
                specs: 'src/main/webapp/specs/*spec.js',
                vendor: '/src/main/webapp/app/lib/angular.min.js',
                helpers: '/src/main/webapp/specs/helpers/angular-mocks.js'
            }
        }
```

But after `grunt:jasmine` i get error 'ReferenceError: `Can't find variable: module`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It's my fail with path to files.
This is solution. Module is not undefined, but I get another error ))

```
jasmine : {
            src : ['src/main/webapp/app/js/controllers/*.js'],
            options: {
                specs: 'src/main/webapp/specs/*spec.js',
                vendor: 'src/main/webapp/app/lib/angular.min.js',
                helpers: 'src/main/webapp/specs/helpers/angular-mocks.js'
            }
        }
```